# Client side file upload using cfs Filesystem

Tags: file-upload, meteor

I am trying to follow [Meteor CollectionFS](https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-CollectionFS) instructions to get a simple file upload working. I have added the following:

In model.js

```
Images = new FS.Collection("images", {
  stores: [new FS.Store.FileSystem("images", {path: "~/uploads"})]
});
```

In Server.js I am publishing this collection and in client.js I am subscribing to it.

On the template event, I get the file and insert it in the collection as following:

```
Images.insert(files[0], function (err, fileObj) {
  //Inserted new doc with ID fileObj._id, and kicked off the data upload using HTTP
  if(err) console.log(err);
});
```

But this throws an error - 500 Meteor.error, Internal server error.
Does someone know why this happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working:

Need to add the Images.allow rules returning true or false.

```
Images.allow({
  insert: function(userId, doc) {
    return (userId && doc.metadata.owner === userId);
  },
  update: function(userId, doc, fieldNames, modifier) {
    return (userId && doc.metadata.owner === userId);
  },
  remove: function(userId, doc) {
    return false;
  }
});
```